# Linux: How can I display all linux users that have an UID between 300 and 500?

Tags: linux, grep, fedora

I want to display all users that its UID between 300 and 500.
I tried the grep command but I can't get the result that I need.

I tried this syntax, but it does not work:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep *:[300-500]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
egrep 'x:3[0-9][0-9]:|x:4[0-9][0-9]:|x:500:' /etc/passwd
```

or more eloquent

```
egrep 'x:[3-4][0-9][0-9]:|x:500:' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Why not combine the first character in `[34]`.  It will fail if such a number appears in any other field, for example in a username or even gid.

Comment: Still did not solve the problem of a number in other fields.

Comment: @unxnut not sure that I understand, for example this is row `avahi:x:107:118:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false` if you want you can add x:[][][] to be sure that you are catching only UID. You are right he wants UID

Comment: What if my password field does not contain `x`?

Comment: @unxnut on Linux that x means here comes password but it is in shadow, is it on Mac different? [http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81590/discussion-between-unxnut-and-filip-bulovic).

Answer (score 2):

Using awk, here is your answer:

```
awk -F: '$3 < 500 && $3 > 300 { print $0 }' /etc/passwd
```

You can `print $1` if you just want the username.

Comment: It returns nothing as result..!!

Comment: I tried it on my Mac before posting.  It worked fine.  As you can see, it is looking at third field (fields separated by `:`) and verifying that it has appropriate UID in which case it prints the entire record.  Can you check that you inserted the filename correctly?  I should have used the complete path (corrected above).